# mod rewrite - do consecutive rules use original, or rewritten url?

Tags: mod-rewrite

If you have two rewrite rules, and the first gets applied, does the second use the rewritten result of the first, or the original URL? I cant find this info in the documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quote from [the documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule):

> Rewrite rules are applied to the results of previous rewrite rules, in the order in which they are defined in the config file. The URL-path or file-system path (see "What is matched?", above) is completely replaced by the Substitution and the rewriting process continues until all rules have been applied, or it is explicitly terminated by an L flag, or other flag which implies immediate termination, such as END or F.